# No reconoce la palabra reservada Compute

Tags: sql-server

Al intentar crear este query en SQL Managament

```
SELECT OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, (UnitPrice * Quantity) FROM [Order Details]
WHERE OrderID < 10260
ORDER BY OrderID
COMPUTE SUM(Quantity) BY OrderId
```

No me reconoce `COMPUTE` estoy utilizando SQL Server 2014 actualmente se usa otra comando, ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cláusula `COMPUTE` [no está soportada desde SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx). La documentación recomienda usar [`ROLLUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) a cambio.

Comment: [Fuente.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338697/cant-execute-a-compute-statement)

Comment: jhhahaha SOen ehh. y me ganaste por 16 segundos

Comment: @Roizpi, he remplazado como me lo indicas y cuando ejecuto la query me dice sintaxis incorrecta cerca de `ROLLUP`

Comment: `SELECT OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, (UnitPrice * Quantity) FROM [Order Details]
WHERE OrderID < 10260
ORDER BY OrderID
ROLLUP SUM(Quantity)`

Comment: SELECT OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, (UnitPrice * Quantity), SUM (Quantity) FROM [Order Details] WHERE OrderID < 10260 GROUP BY ROLLUP (OrderID)      .    Ver [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: @Roizpi La columna 'Order Details.ProductID' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: He añadido la referencia a la documentación de [ROLLUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) en la respuesta:

Comment: lo solucionaste ¿verdad?, GROUP BY ROLLUP ((OrderID, ProductID))

Comment: @Roizpi, Si lo solucione gracias `SELECT OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, (UnitPrice * Quantity), SUM (Quantity) FROM [Order Details] 
WHERE OrderID < 10260
GROUP BY ROLLUP (OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity)`